# MySQL + Windows and the lowercase table name

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to fix a problem of the lowercase table names in the MySQL on Windows. I've found that topic [MySQL Lowercase Table Names in Windows Uppercase names on Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172382/mysql-lowercase-table-names-in-windows-uppercase-names-on-unix) but even if I've done the same as it is described in that topic's updated descrpition, the problem had remained. Why ?

Comment: I am not interested in answering your question because you keep deleting your question without knowing the valuable helper. No one knows when you delete your question.

Comment: I delete my questions if I successful fixed the problem by myself when no one post have posted the solution. I just don't want to make a mess on that site

Comment: The best thing is post your solution as an answer here. So that if anyone face the same problem can get beneficial. This is how the SO is supposed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where to change the value of lower_case_table_names=2 on windows xampp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550789/where-to-change-the-value-of-lower-case-table-names-2-on-windows-xampp)

Comment: Instead of editing you question you can post it as an answer and can accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed, here's the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/8550870/106616