# Force mysql objects to be uppercase in django

Tags: mysql, django

Is there an option to set the names of every mysql objects (tables and columns) in uppercase?

If not, what is the reason ?

Comment: What would be the reason *for*?

Comment: A database shared by several people. Some use django, others don't. The convention is to set every name in uppercase

Comment: Okay. But that's a policy issue, not a Django issue.

Answer (score 0):

if your problem is uppercases table names and uppercases field names, you must be look at this page [MySQL Lowercase Table Names in Windows Uppercase names on Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172382/mysql-lowercase-table-names-in-windows-uppercase-names-on-unix)