# Grails DB Migration Plugin - Weird Behaviour

Tags: grails, dbmigrate

I just came across a weird behavior while running dbm-update. It created two sets of databasechangelog and databasechangelock tables. One set with all Upper case and second with all lower case. The last update went only in the newly created log.

It has been running fine so far. One difference I see is that on our Production environment the log files are all UPPER Case while on Test they are all lower case.

Could it be that we are running dbm-update from both Windows and Mac machines?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could it be that we are running dbm-update from both Windows and Mac machines?

Yes

But I think it is more a problem of the underlying database. MySQL for example creates lower case table names on Windows while it uses upper case table names on Unix system (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172382/mysql-lowercase-table-names-in-windows-uppercase-names-on-unix) question).

If you export a mysql database on an unix system and import the data on a windows system you get different database names than if you create the database from scratch on the windows system.

If you then run dbm-update the `databasechangelog` table isn't found and a new `databasechangelog` table is created.

Comment: Yeah.. this seems like the issue. Thanks.